# bzr : Is it possible to switch between revisions offline?

Tags: version-control, bazaar

I am using the "bzr update -r ${revisionNo}" command to switch between revisions. But it is slow and it seems to do network operations. Why?

I have checked out the whole repo so all revisions must be in my local. Why does it connect to network then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat speculative, but I would guess that you are working with a [bound branch](http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/BzrUsingBoundBranches). A bound branch is still linked to the location that you checked out from and will consult it for certain operations. A bound branch is created if you use `bzr checkout` instead of `bzr branch`. It exists to simulate CVS- or subversion-like behavior, where you're operating on a central repository.

Fast `update` is not supported because that's not the intended mode of operation for bound branches. You can revisit older revisions that you have stored locally using one of `bzr checkout --lightweight`, `bzr export`, or `bzr revert`, however.

In order to work completely offline, you can use `bzr unbind` or `bzr reconfigure --tree` to convert an existing bound branch into an unbound branch. Warning: if you do this, you will have to push your commits explicitly with `bzr push` before they become visible in the remote repository. You can use `bzr bind` to make the branch bound again.

And while it is unlikely, it is also possible to encounter such a scenario when creating a "stacked branch". A stacked branch reuses history from a different branch, and if that branch is not local, then most bzr operations will have to go through the network. It is created with `bzr branch --stacked` and is normally intended for use on a server to save space. You can convert a stacked branch into an unstacked branch with `bzr reconfigure --unstacked`.